# I can't use setOnClickListener in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

i am trying to set up a second page for my android app but when i try to do it my setOnClickListener is red here is the code part:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val MainActivity2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    Button.setOnClickListener {
        val Intent = Intent(this,MainActivity2::class.java)
        startActivity(Intent)
    }
```

Does anyone know why the setOnClickListener is red ? (the Button. is not red)

Comment: where have you assigned the `Button` variable, I can only see `MainActivity2` to be a button thus use it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assigned your button into the variable named MainActivity2. You do not currently have a variable named Button I assume.
You need to use

MainActivity2.setOnClickListener
{*code here*}
instead

Another way for you to do the same thing:

In your xml file for your Button element, you can add an onClicked attribute.
Example:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:onClick="deleteAll"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

In your kotlin file which uses that xml file for the view:

```
fun deleteAll(view: View) {
    doSomething()
}
```